# Retrieving OIDC URL in Terraform for EKS Cluster without HTTPS

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

How can we get OIDC URL without Https in terraform for already existing EKS Cluster

I need the OIDC URL without Https ( for example the data module will fetch the oidc from existing EKS ).

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cluster_autoscaler_sts_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(, "https://", "")}:sub"
      values   = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler"]
    }
    principals {
      identifiers = []
      type        = "Federated"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem like what you want. Is there any other code you have which would be relevant to the question?